# How to run 'Hello world' in PyCharm Community 2020

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to use PyCharm for all my Python coding, but can't figure-out how to run 'Hello world' without creating a project in PyCharm Community 2020.
My focus is learning various Python features/functionality.  So I write a large number of small files with <100 lines of code.  Being forced to create a project for such simple needs seems counter-intuitive.
The menus and context menus don't seem helpful.  Screenshots attached.
[View Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDSZG.jpg) [Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byZpP.jpg)

Comment: Would using Spyder as the IDE be an option?  It’s much simpler than PyCharm.

Comment: Why don't you just create 1 project and then put all your files in that 1 project?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add additional .py files to your project directory.
Having bunch of files in the one project directory should work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PyCharm for Python I am pretty sure you have also installed Python. This means you have an application called "Python 3.8 (32-bit)" or something similar to it. In this application, you can run type code for python without creating a project in PyCharm.

Let me know if that helps or if you need further clarification.